# Using EntityManager and DataSource together in a LocalBean

Tags: jpa

I wanted to do some scheduled JDBC job within a bean.

And I got.

```
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Error in allocating a connection.
Cause: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Local transaction already has 1 non-XA Resource:
cannot add more resources.
Error Code: 0
```

```java
@LocalBean @Stateless
class MyBean {

    public void doJPA() {
    }

    @Schedule
    public void doJDBC() {
    }

    @PersistentContext
    EntityManager entityManager;

    @Resource
    DataSource dataSource;
}
```

Did I do anything wrong?

Do I just have to split the bean?

Thank you.

Comment: Why do you need DataSource? Isn't enough EntityManager?

Comment: Cuz, as annotated, I need to do some batch job which is not good with JPA, such as updating whole table rows.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the same DataSource as JPA is using, the server should give you the same connection, so you should not get this error.  Are you using a different data source?

You could also get the JDBC Connection from your EntityManager using unwrap()

See,
http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/EMAPI#Getting_a_JDBC_Connection_from_an_EntityManager

Comment: If the DataSource is injected, the server will provide new connection each time.

Comment: They are the same jdbc resource. The `unwrap(T)` method is provider specific, isn't it?